# arbitrary reparametrization

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

Let $\alpha: (a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ of class $C^{\infty}$ with $\Vert\alpha^{\prime}\Vert>0 $ then if $\{ k,m,n\} \subset \mathbb{R}_+$ there repametrizacion $\beta: (m,n)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\Vert \beta^{\prime}\Vert<k$ ?

I think just do the following: $s(t)=k\int_a^t \Vert \alpha^{\prime}(u)\Vert du$ and find $h:(m,n) \rightarrow (0,kL)$, diffeomorphism such that $\Vert h^{\prime}\Vert<k^2$ and make $\beta=s^{-1}\circ h$ I wonder how to find such $h$ ?

I would appreciate any suggestions to find the reparametrization